# Nth-of-type ignored classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have this html

```
<div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item inactive"></div>
    <div class="item inactive"></div>
<div>
```

And this css

```
 .item.inactive:nth-of-type(1) {
     do stuff for 1st inactive
 }
 .item.inactive:nth-of-type(2) {
     do stuff for 2nd inactive
 }
```

but it's not working as expected.

Instead I see this behavior

```
 .item.inactive:nth-of-type(2) {
     stuff is happening for 1st inactive
 }
```

so is it just ignoring when I specified .inactive? How would I get the effect I want?

```css
.item {
  color: red;
}

.item.inactive:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class='item-list'>
  <li class='item'>item 1</li>
  <li class='item inactive'>item 2</li>
  <li class='item inactive'>item 3</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/. I think you don't use the proper selector.

Answer (score 1):

`nth-of-type` works on tag `type` and no `class`. when you write:

```
.item.inactive:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: red;
}
```

affect on first `div` if have both class item and inactive.first div have class item and no inactive so no selected.

```
.item.inactive:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

affect on Second `div` if have both class item and inactive.Second div have class item and inactive so selected.

**You can use This :**

```
div:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
div:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="item">This is 0</div>
  <div class="item inactive">This is 1</div>
  <div class="item inactive">This is 2</div>
```

Comment: This is not a solution for his answer, you just point out the problem w/o any suggestion. At least you should take his code and replace it with something else (ie: nth-child) so it can solve the thread.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can get my desired effect in css then?

Comment: What if the list was 200 items long and only the last 2 were the target?

Comment: @sheriffderek use of jquery or change html code and use of other selectors.

Comment: @Kiwad: Have you considered that it might be because there *is no* solution to this problem in pure CSS? I'd like to see you solve the problem using :nth-child() (and no, .item.inactive:nth-child(3) is *not* the solution, if that's what you have in mind).

Comment: @BoltClock Give me more explanation please!

Comment: @ehsan that is what i gave in my answer.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , you are right.i change my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock , Thankyou.

Comment: @ehsan, Sorry to trouble you , but what if the webpage container more no of div's? will that code snippet work ?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , if  `<div>Test</div>` be between both `<div class="item inactive"></div>`, so don't work your answer.we do not hypothesize,We make a solution for html code that see it now.

Comment: My Question was why are you using nth-child directly on the <div>, but not on the class.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar , There is no difference in result.we can use it on class too.

Answer (score 0):

nth-of-type:-It is defined in the CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a “structural pseudo-class”, meaning it is used to style content based on its relationship with parent and sibling elements.

[nth-of-type reference](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)

Try this CSS

```
 .inactive:nth-of-type(2) {
    color:blue;
 }
 .inactive:nth-of-type(3){
    color:red;
 }
```

hope this helps..

Comment: How about a working code snippet? I just tried what you suggest...

Comment: @sheriffderek what would be the code if he want to style the first .inactive element and second .inactive element?

Comment: Probably JavaScript... I couldn't think of a CSS solution. nth-of-type seems to deal with `type` and children. {{emoji.shrug}}